# umount doesn't remove all references

Tags: linux, mount

I run the command `umount /mnt/data` and it seems to work. One of the entries that point to that folder is removed from the output of `mount` command:

Before:

```
$ mount | grep /mnt/data
/dev/sdb on /mnt/data type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,data=ordered)
/dev/sdd on /mnt/data type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,data=ordered)
```

After:

```
$ umount /mnt/data
$ mount | grep /mnt/data
/dev/sdb on /mnt/data type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,data=ordered)
```

However I still see an entry(/dev/sdb) pointing to this folder in the output. Also running `ls /mnt/data` returns an error:

```
ls: reading directory '/mnt/data': Input/output error
```

PS: At this point `/etc/fstab` file has a single entry:

```
UUID=d11402a4-b585-4f51-ac49-05e11ddacf7d / ext4 defaults 1 1
```

Comment: The first question is: why do you have to drives mounted to the same location ?

Comment: @mrc02_kr not sure how they got there

Comment: Ok. Can you add to answer you /etc/fstab file ?

Comment: @mrc02_kr ok, done

Comment: You can try to unmount it specyfying drive not mountpoint . For example: `umount /dev/sdb`. The weird thing is that you don't have partition created on this drive (or at least there is mounter whole disk not partition). Could you also include output of `lsblk`?

Comment: Is the mountpoint referring to `/dev/sdb` from a previous, maybe manual mount attempt? Is the disk `/dev/sdb` actually there?

Comment: thanks guys, your comments helped me solve the issue

Comment: And how? Pls share so others learn from it.

Comment: @RudiC just did

Answer (score 1):

It seems I had a 'dangling' drive pointing to same mount point(no idea how i got it). `umount /mnt/data` was removing only one of those and the folder was pointing to non-existent drive(hence input/output error)

When I run `umount /mnt/data` second time the `/dev/sdb` also got removed from output and `ls` did not give errors anymore.